# how to stop page refresh on form submit in jQuery-Validation-Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

how to stop page refresh on form submit in jQuery-Validation-Engine
I'm using 4 tabs with each has different form, but on submit it should stay in same tab...

```
$('#AddPartnerSubmitBtn').live('click', function () { 
  var formvalidate; 
  formvalidate=$("#AddPartner").validationEngine("validate"); 
   if(formvalidate==1) { } 
 });
```

Comment: Without knowing you code it is hard to guess. But most likely you need to prevent de default behavior of the submit event.

Comment: Submit your code along with your question.

Comment: make a fiddle || add some code with your tests plz

Comment: Use `$.ajax` to submit your form.

Comment: use **event.PreventDefault**

Comment: $('#AddPartnerSubmitBtn').live('click', function () {
var formvalidate;
 formvalidate=$("#AddPartner").validationEngine("validate");
 if(formvalidate==1)
{
}
});

This is my code, on click of submit i'm calling validate function,but it should not refresh page.

Comment: $('#AddPartnerSubmitBtn').live('click', function () {
var formvalidate;
 formvalidate=$("#AddPartner").validationEngine("validate");
 if(formvalidate==1)
{
}
});

This is my code, on click of submit i'm calling validate function,but it should not refresh page.

Comment: use `on` if ur using the latest version of jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault`

```
$('#AddPartnerSubmitBtn').live('click', function (event) { 

  // this will prevent the form from submitting 
  event.preventDefault();

  var formvalidate; 
  formvalidate=$("#AddPartner").validationEngine("validate"); 
  if(formvalidate==1) { } 
 });
```

Comment: I think it would be wise to use the on-submit on the form instead of an on-click handler on the button. If the form is submitted in an other way, it is not guaranteed that this event will fire.